# Synchronizing two threads

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

I have two threads and I want the second thread to wait until first thread finishes.  How can I accomplish this?

This my code:

```
public class NewClass1 implements Runnable {

    // in main
    CallMatlab c = new CallMatlab();
    CUI m = new CUI();
    Thread t1 = new Thread(c);
    t1.start();
    Thread t2 = new Thread(m);
    try {
      t1.join();
    } catch (InterruptedException ex) { 
      Logger.getLogger(NewClass1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    t2.start();

  //
  public void run() {
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not su..");
  }
}
```

Comment: @MOUZA: You've posted your code in a comment, which is pretty much unreadable... please include it in the question instead, by editing the question.  Indent it by four spaces and it will be nicely formatted in the question.

Comment: I added it, but it's not a complete working code sample (possibly it was stripped down to fit in the comment box).

Answer (score 9):

Use the [`Thread.join()`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) method. From the second thread, call

```
firstThread.join();
```

There are optional overloads which take timeouts, too. You'll need to handle `InterruptedException` in case your second thread is interrupted before the first thread completes.

Answer (score 4):

You need to call:

```
first_thread.join();
```

from the second thread.

See the [Thread.join documentation](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()).

Answer (score 1):

Just for the sake of covering all basics, you could also use semaphores.

In the waiter

```
/* spawn thread */
/* Do interesting stuff */
sem.acquire();
```

In the waitee

```
/* wake up in the world */
/* do intersting stuff */
sem.release();
```

This approach is in no way superior if the waitee is just going to terminate, but semaphores are interesting, so I think it was worth stating.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your first thread is doing something useful at the same time as the second thread, you may be better off with one thread. If they are both doing something useful, use join() as has been suggested.

Comment: this my code

public class NewClass1 implements Runnable {

    in main

        CallMatlab c = new CallMatlab();
        CUI m = new CUI();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(c);
         t1.start();
       
           
       

        Thread t2 = new Thread(m);
        try {
            t1.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(NewClass1.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        t2.start();
       
             

 
    public void run() {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not su..");

Answer (score 0):

You may also consider using the [java.util.concurrent](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html) package. CountDownLatch or CyclicBarrier can be used for coordinating threads, while Executors are nice for managing concurrent tasks.