# Ordering the execution of Threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization

Please have a look at the code below:

**Class A**

```
package generalscenarios;

public class A implements Runnable{

    public void run(){

        System.out.println("dsad");

    }

}
```

**Class B**

```
package generalscenarios;


public class B {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        A a1  = new A();
        Thread a = new Thread(a1);
        a.start();
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

When I execute the class B, My thread a will be started by the main thread, And hi will be printed on console by the main thread. But the order of printing "hi" and "dsad" is not determined.

I want that "hi" should be printed after "dsad".

The solution that I thought of is to take a shared variable between main thread and thread "a". Main thread will wait on that variable till the time thread "a" notifies him.

**Class A**

```
package generalscenarios;

public class A implements Runnable{

    public void run(){

        System.out.println("dsad");
        synchronized (this) {
            this.notify();  
        }


    }

}
```

**Class B**

```
package generalscenarios;


public class B {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        A a1  = new A();
        Thread a = new Thread(a1);
        a.start();
        synchronized (a1) {
            a1.wait();
        }
        System.out.println("hi");
    }
}
```

**Please suggest me if my thinking is valid. Please suggest any other way of achieving this.**

Comment: You could look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/873237/synchronizing-two-threads - Thread.join() might just be the ticket.

Comment: why don't you join the thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try something like

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

    A a1  = new A();
    Thread a = new Thread(a1);
    a.start();
    a.join();
    System.out.println("hi");
}
```

Do read [Thread.join()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) and also read the complete reference of `Thread`.